# How to prevent creation of new instance of controller on $location hash search param change.

Tags: javascript, hash, angularjs

I have many filters on my page. I am using $location.search to save search parameters in hash.  But angular is creating new controller instance on every search param change which I want to prevent.

I don't want to create new instance of controller on each $location.search() call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating the route definition set `reloadOnSearch` to `false`

```
angular.module('ngView', ['$routeProvider', function(routeProvider) {
  routeProvider.when('/my-path', {
    templateUrl: 'my-template.html',
    controller: 'MyController',
    reloadOnSearch : false
  });

}]);
```

- [Route](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route)
- [Route Provider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeProvider)